# String to NSDate then back to string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a date in **NSString** format with the following format:

```
2012-03-27 14:43:22 +0000 //this is a string
```

What I want is to somehow convert this to say: `March 27`

So I figured the way to do this was to convert this string to an NSDate, then format the new NSDate to my desired format, then back to string, but I'm getting null output:

```
NSString *date=[sectionInfo name];
NSLog(@"date:%@", date);
NSDateFormatter *k= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[k setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-DD hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *d=[k dateFromString:date];
NSLog(@"%@", d);

NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
[df setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd"];
NSString *dateString=[df stringFromDate:d];
NSLog(@"dateString:%@", dateString);
```

Output:

```
date:2012-03-28 14:43:22 +0000
(null)
dateString:(null)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your format string should be `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"`

Also, try using `getObjectValue:forString:range:error:` method instead of `dateFromString:` and take a look at the error returned.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have capital HH in your format, also change the a to z, like this:

```
[k setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-DD HH:mm:ss z"];
```